# Repartition drive without caring what's on it

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, fdisk

I've got a microSDHC which appears to have a broken partition table. When I plugged it in there where a lot of folders and I was able to copy some files of it. But most files had a filesize 0 and most folders where empty. I was planning creating one big ext4 partition of the entire card anyways so I don't really care for the content. But I ran into some trouble. Gparted just hangs, so I tried with fdisk and this is it's output:

```
    Disk /dev/sdd: 31.4 GB, 31393316864 bytes
    64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 29939 cylinders, total 61315072 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x65207265

    This doesn't look like a partition table
    Probably you selected the wrong device.

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdd1   ?   234827378  2171105915   968139269   65  Novell Netware 386
    /dev/sdd2   ?  1803121236  3655242430   926060597+  6c  Unknown
    /dev/sdd3   ?  1835999346  3754988772   959494713+  74  Unknown
    /dev/sdd4   ?  2885681152  2885735624       27236+   0  Empty
```

Now this does not look like a healty system. But again the only goal is to remove all the partitions on it and have one big ext4. How would I do this?

Comment: Did you use dd to copy ISO to flash drive? That does not use standard partitions and data ends up in standard location for partition table. That looks like fdisk is trying to parse random data into a partition table. You can use dd to erase MBR. But be absolutely sure you have correct drive for sdX, as you erase data. DD's nickname is Data Destroyer as it does exactly what you say, not what you mean. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`

Comment: You would also need to partition, and set a filesystem after @oldfred 's comment with `dd`. You can use the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition) from ubuntu website, or use `fdisk` and `makefs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Run `parted` as root: in a terminal: `sudo parted /dev/sdd` (you will be prompted for your `sudo` password)
2. Create a new partition table: in `parted`: `mklabel gpt`
3. Exit: in `parted`: `q`

And see if GParted is able to handle the device.

Comment: If you use gpt which I also recommend you need either a bios_grub partition if drive will every be used as a boot drive in BIOS or an efi partition if ever UEFI boot. I suggest those partitions even if drive is currently planned as data only, as in future you may want to experiment with another install or convert drive. Efi partition should be first on drive, so difficult to add later if drive has lots of data.